# php.ini error_reporting set to E_ALL but not working

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

In my `php.ini` file on wampserver I have the following lines set:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

Yet, I have to actually call `error_reporting(E_ALL)` in my script in order for it to actually show the errors.

Why is this happening? I'm getting to my `php.ini` through the wampserver icon -> php -> php.ini

Comment: I believe there is another option you need to enable: display_startup_errors

Comment: Also how you come to know that it's not working?  instead of changing into php.ini change in your code file like `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);?>`

Comment: I know it isn't working because when I add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to my script it shows me a fatal PHP error. When I removed `error_reporting(E_ALL)` from my script it shows me a blank page. I've tried changing `error_reporting` to `E_ALL | E_STRICT` and that didn't help.

Comment: `display_startup_errors` is already `On`.

Comment: wat version of php you are using

Comment: PHP version 5.6.25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the `@` suppression modifier in front of `call_user_func_array` in my Router front-end controller class which was resetting `error_reporting` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

In WAMPServer there are 2 `php.ini` files:

1. `\wamp\bin\php\php{version}\php.ini`  (controls only PHP CLI)
2. and the one that controls the Apache/PHP environment.

Edit the Apache version by using the `wampmanager` menus, so you get the right one.

```
wampmanager->PHP->php.ini
```

This will open the correct file in your default editor. Change the parameters in this file, save it and restart Apache.

**BEWARE:** If as you say you are using the correct method to edit the correct file -

> These parameters are also documented at the top of the `php.ini` file, do not change the documentation version, look further down the file and edit the actual parameters there.

Comment: this is correct and well descriptive. And important is to restart apache

Comment: I already did this....and my phpinfo() tells me `error_ reporting` is set to `32767`.

Comment: I dont suppose you are turning errors OFF somewhere in an include that everything includes are you? Grasping at straws now

Comment: No. What is weird is I am using an MVC framework I coded and if I put `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of the bootstrap file it doesn't work, I have to actually put that code in the file causing the fatal error itself. Also, I checked and no composer package is manipulating any php.ini settings.

Comment: OK this is bizarre. When I run a script that only contains `phpinfo()` its telling me `error_reporting` is set to `32767`. However, I just put `phpinfo()` in the script not showing the errors, and its telling me the `error_reporting` value is `0`. I ransacked the entire project and nowhere is `error_reporting` or `ini_set` being defined.

Comment: It seems that `error_reporting` is being reset inside of my class methods. I just read on the PHP website `The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined function`. Does this mean that PHP will always ignore my ini settings for fatal error reporting within class methods?

Comment: That is not a default condition. there must be something somewhere specifically turning error reporting off. **What framework are you using?**

Comment: [Like I said earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279497/php-ini-error-reporting-set-to-e-all-but-not-working/42279642?noredirect=1#comment71716680_42279642)